Typegoose virtuals are not populating
I have two models - Posts and Comments. Comments belong to Posts.
@modelOptions({
  schemaOptions: {
    timestamps: true,
  },
})
export class Comment {
  @prop({ required: true })
  content!: string;

  @prop({
    ref: () => Post,
    required: true,
  })
  public postId!: Ref<Post>;
 }

@modelOptions({
   schemaOptions: {
    timestamps: true,
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  },
})
export class Post {
  @prop({ required: true })
  title!: string;

  @prop({ required: true })
  content!: string;

  @prop({ ref: () => Comment, type: () => [Comment] })
  comments: Ref<Comment>[];
}

Here is the query:
const posts: Post[] = await PostModel.find().populate("comments");

I am getting an empty array when I am certain related records exist in the database. Why is this happening?

You are currently using normal references, this means you have to have the ids of the comments stored in the Post's reference array (comments) and have them saved to the database (in that array).
What you likely actually want are virtual references (or also called virtual populate):
export class Post {
  @prop({ ref: () => Comment, foreignField: "postId", localField: "_id" })
  comments: Ref<Comment>[];
}

(code reduced to relevant parts)
Also see Typegoose's Virtual Populate doc.
